# Preact component style not rendered successfully

Tags: preact

I switched from react to preact but my own components not render successfully maybe for styles

can anyone help me?

```
//MyComponent.js
import style from "./style.css";

let Component = () => (
    <div style={style.home}>
      <p>How are you today?</p>
    </div>
  );
export default Component;
```

and

```
//style.css
.home {
    margin: 56px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS Module loader returns class names which you should assign to `class` prop instead of `style`.

Here is the modified code.

```
//MyComponent.js
import style from "./style.css";

let Component = () => (
    // Use class and not style
    <div class={style.home}>
      <p>How are you today?</p>
    </div>
  );
  
export default Component;
```

Comment: Just to add for OP, this style of CSS is called CSS Modules. I reckon that was part of the confusion, not being able to find any information on what is happening.